# Knockout.js - how do I get the value of an observable property inside a computed observable?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have following Knockout.js object:

```
var viewModel = {
    description : ko.observable(""),
    Name : ko.observable(""),
    productid : ko.observable(""),
    productmodel : ko.observable(""),
    productnumber : ko.observable(""),
    text_relevance : ko.observable(""),
    mydunamicfield : ko.computed(function() {
        return "bq=(and " +
            ((this.description == "") ? "" : ("description:" + this.description + " ")) +
            ")";
    } , this)
};
```

But the `mydunamicfield`property isn't producing the the correct concatenated result. If I try to reference `this.description()` inside another function, I see the following error message when the page is loading:

```
Property 'description' of object [object Window] is not a function
```

What is the problem in this case?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Firstly, you must reference `this.description` as `this.description()` if you want to get its value.

Secondly, try putting your `computed` field outside your `viewModel` (as `'this'` which is the `viewModel` itself isn't defined at the point you create the `computed` observable.

See http://jsfiddle.net/rAEqK/2/ for a working example.